# Drop network packages

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

I'm seeing a lot more protocols in the `wireshark` capture in my university network than in my home network and the connection is incredibly bad at the university (> 2 Min. to get an IP address from DHCP server due to package losses in the worst cases). I'd like to setup package dropping in order to improve connectivity and have the following questions

- Does my approach make sense? Or can packages which I see in wireshark not be dropped at any of the following levels of abstraction/the stack

  - at the device (with the driver)
  - on other part of hardware (with the driver or another kernel module)
  - in the kernel
- Which command to use?

**EDIT 1:** The problems are confirmed on Windows XP, Vista, 8; Mac OS X; Linux 3.2.x, 3.8.x, 3.13.x, 3.14.x and 3.15.x and Android 4.0. It is part of the [eduroam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduroam) network (of networks) and definitely should allow arbitrary clients to connect. The problems are knwon on server side and the IT dep. is working on it. My intention is to speed things up on my client machine. But my question is really quite limited to the specific idea of package dropping on client side.

Comment: unless you are a network administrator at the school, and can configure the network hardware, nothing you can do will affect the congestion you are experiencing. the issue is not that your computer is dropping the dhcp or other packets you send, its that their equipment in their data center is.

Comment: Basic Troubleshooting. Do other people find the same problem with their computers? And have you visited the IT Dept at your university? Maybe they are not so accomodating to non-uni laptops plugged in